# Override string in a library with explicit package

Tags: android, xml, string, overriding

I know that i have to keep the same name to override a resource of a library, but imagine a class inside this library that is using a string.

With an example i'll be more clear i think:

**Library class:**

```
package com.library.randomlibrarypackage;

import com.library.R;

public class RandomClass extends Activity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String stringFromResource = getString(R.string.librarystring);
    }
}
```

This string is contained under library's values resources:

```
<resources>
    <string name="librarystring">This is from library</string>
</resources>
```

If i try to "override" it and use `RandomClass.class`, the value of `stringFromResource` still remains "This is from library".

There's a way to override it without override the entire class?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to override it in gradle build file for your library like this

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        debug{
            resValue "string", "librarystring", "Library string debug"
        }
        release {
            resValue "string", "librarystring", "Library string release"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a maven project so i can't modify the gradle file

Comment: @Fondesa can you download the library manually and add it or it that not an option?

Comment: I can do it but it's not an option. I mean that i can add the jar files manually but it's not a good option considering that is a library with live updates.
Btw if it's not possible to override this string i can ask to library's owner for a custom method or simply i'll not override this string (it's not strictly necessary). Anyway thanks for your answer, i didn't know this way to override resources.

Comment: @Fondesa maybe there is another way, but I don't know any other way. This is how I have been providing the base server url according to flavor. You could create a separate XML for each flavor, but it is easier to maintain this way.

Comment: Obviously i can't accept your answer because it wasn't a solution, but sure you deserve a +1 for this method, thanks again, i didn't know it, in future cases i'll try it with jar projects.